# What sensors would be suitable for measuring masses of the range 0.5 g to 1g?

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, embedded, microprocessor, component-selection

I am working on a project that involves measuring objects whose masses range from .5g to 1g.

Preferably looking for something small and thin but at this point, anything that accomplishes the task is also welcomed.
I did some research on force-sensing resistors and even though their physical dimension was suitable for my project, I am yet to find one that is capable of measuring masses ranging from 0.5g-1g.

(Project details -> The object would be mounted stationarily on a platform with the sensor underneath the platform. The sensor then produces an electrical value that can be used to deduce the objects' mass/weight).
Thanks

**Update 8/22/2020.**
Since the previous accuracy requirement was extremely difficult to achieve I have refined the accuracy requirements.
Accuracy +- 0.05g

Comment: What about accuracy and resolution?

Comment: A load cell or force transducer?

Comment: All of this depends on mechanics more than anything else. If the electronics can be mounted together with the plate or whatever you put the weight on, then you should be able to measure the weight with a MEMS accelerometer and Newton's laws F=m * a * a.

Comment: @Lundin F = m * a² ?

Comment: @Andyaka  I posted an update to the thanks for your response

Comment: @Jeroen3 either will do so far as the can measure masses ranging between 0.5-1g. If you know of any such sensors please don't hesitate to post it. thanks

Comment: If you don't care about mass then use a couple of go-no-go light beam detectors.

Comment: @Lundin, since the object being measured, is stationary(a = 0).Hence, F=m*a in my scenario, would be zero(F = 0). Instead, my setup would be making use of gravity, F = mg. Hence, I don't think an accelerometer will be appropriate for me. Thanks for your response tho.

Comment: @Andyaka light objects as in objects that weigh less. I rephrased the question.

Comment: Well, we can make scales measuring micrograms, so 1 gram should not be that much of a technical challenge. You just may need to engineer some mechanics.

Comment: @Jeroen3 that great but any known sensors available commercially that do exactly that?

Comment: [Product recommendations are off topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You've not stated an accuracy requirement.  A small digital scale for jewelry will cost around $10 and you can rip out the electronics and use an hx711 instead.  But beware you'll need to rezero before the reading.

Comment: @African_king My solution is based on the assumption that you have a plate, spring etc. Again, start with figuring out what mechanics that are feasible, then adapt the electronics accordingly.

Comment: Solves what problem?  Without an accuracy spec, you have an object detection problem, not a weighing one!

Comment: _"Accuracy +-0.01%"_ - you're dreaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach that I would consider is to use a voice-coil with an extremely compliant surround. You might be able to re-purpose an old loudspeaker - you would have to experiment.

Add a sensor to the voice coil assembly so you can determine whether the voice coil has moved. You don't need to accurately know how far it has moved. But the sensor must be accurate in terms of whether the coil has moved away from the home position.

Next, you need an adjustable current source. The idea is that you increase the current to move the voice coil back to the home position. The current can be adjusted manually or can be part of a feedback loop that adjusts the current automatically.

The most accurate weight measuring devices that I have both used and repaired use this technique.

The idea is that any non-linearity in the voice coil is cancelled out because the voice coil is driven back to the home position. The current required to drive the voice coil is directly proportional to the weight on the vpice coil.

Comment: Nice in theory, but achieving an accuracy of Accuracy +-0.01% will be extremely difficult.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott - Nice in practice, also, since this method (ie. the Kibble balance) is pretty close to how the kilogram is defined in terms of Plancks constant.

Answer (score 1):

Weighing small masses is not easy, even more if you are restricted with respect to physical dimensions. You should look at how people who work in areas with similar requirements are handling such issues, for example, diamond traders or biologists.

Mettler-Toledo is an important supplier of scales for laboratories. Look at their [laboratory balances](https://www.mt.com/int/en/home/products/Laboratory_Weighing_Solutions.html). You'll see that even standard laboratory equipment is not good enough. And I can tell you that their high-precision balances will still not help you much unless you control the environment (no air circulation, constant moisture,...).

If you don't have to measure the weight of an object in rest, you could achieve better results, though. (Of course, the above equipment is not specifically tailored for your needs, so you could indeed build a better scale.)